# Can I redirect alerts from a single DataDog monitor to different Slack channels?

Tags: slack, slack-api, datadog

So I've got a DataDog monitor and its query is roughly similar to:

```
trace-analytics("service:foo-service @http.status_code:403").rollup("count").last("10m") > 1000
```

and under "Notify your team" section of DD monitor I setup my team's channel on Slack and we receive quite a lot of alerts as a result.

That said, we'd be interested to redirect those errors to relevant teams (e.g., if the route `/abc` throws a `403` we'd like to post it to another #abc-team Slack channel, `/cde` to `#cde-team` etc). How can we do it? I was thinking I could write a Slack bot or something since I didn't find such an option on DataDog.

Answer (score 5):

You would need some kinda of tag that is an exact string match on some part of the slack channel (so the tag would need to be `route:abc` not `route:/abc`)

then you would be able to write something like `@slack-{{route.name}}-alerts`. which automatically dereferences the tag and sends it out to the appropriate group.

[image: monitor message description]

https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/tagging-best-practices/#create-automatic-dynamic-alerts-for-your-team

If for some reason you can't get a tag that matches any part of your slack handle onto the data, you could make a giant if else conditional

```
{{#is_match "route.name" "/abc"}}
  @slack-abc
{{/is_match}}
{{#is_match "route.name" "/whoever"}}
  @slack-whoever
{{/is_match}}
{{#is_match "route.name" "/turtle"}}
  @slack-turtle
{{/is_match}}
{{^is_match "route.name" "/abc" "/whoever" "/turtle"}}
  please make sure that this endpoint is configured to forward to the proper team's channel inside this monitor
  @slack-backup-alert-channel
{{/is_match}}
```

https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/notifications/?tab=monitors#conditional-variables

the first option is much cleaner and scales way better obviously. but i've seen people use the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much aware about the DataDog functionality, but I can help you with Slack Bot.

The bot you can develop will have following flow:

1. All the alerts will be sent to common channel `#all-alerts`
2. The bot will also be invited to this channel
3. Subscribe the bot to `message` event
4. Process the received event(message), determine which team it belongs to.
5. Post the processed message/alert to relevant team.